# TO DO LIST in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a delete button beside each of the items that are to be added.
How to do this properly so the all the functions work?

I have tried the method below as you will see in the code. This seems correct to me but it's not working. This needs to be purely JavaScript`.

```
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var li = document.createElement("li");
function handleAddNewItem() //adds new items and more
{
   var item = document.getElementById("input").value;
   var ul = document.getElementById("list");
   var li = document.createElement("li");

   if (item === '') {
      alert("Input field can not be empty");
   }
   else {
      button.innerText = "Delete";
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("- " + item));
      ul.appendChild(li);
      ul.appendChild(button);
   }
   document.getElementById("input").value = ""; //clears input

   //li.onclick = clearDom;
}//code deletes items by clearDom function

document.body.onkeyup = function (e) //allows items to be added with enter button
{
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      handleAddNewItem();
   }
}

function clearDom() {
   //e.target.parentElement.removeChild(e.target);//removeChild used
   ul.removeChild(li);
   ul.removeChild(button);
}

button.addEventListener("click", clearDom);




<body>
   <input id="input" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
   <button id="add_button" onclick="handleAddNewItem()">ADD</button>
   <ul id="list">
   </ul>
</body>
<script src="new.js"></script>

</html>
```

```js
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var li = document.createElement("li");

function handleAddNewItem() //adds new items and more
{
  var item = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  if (item === '') {
    alert("Input field can not be empty");
  } else {
    button.innerText = "Delete";
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("- " + item));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    ul.appendChild(button);
  }
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; //clears input

  //li.onclick = clearDom;
} //code deletes items by clearDom function

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) //allows items to be added with enter button
{
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    handleAddNewItem();
  }
}

function clearDom() {
  //e.target.parentElement.removeChild(e.target);//removeChild used
  ul.removeChild(li);
  ul.removeChild(button);
}

button.addEventListener("click", clearDom);
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
<button id="add_button" onclick="handleAddNewItem()">ADD</button>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
<!-- commented out to reduce errors in the console
<script src="new.js"></script> -->
```

I am facing this error for now-

> "The node to be removed is not a child of this node. at
>   HTMLButtonElement.clearDom new.js:33:7"

I want to implement the delete button in line with the items listed. so that it deletes the items added one by one separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function handleAddNewItem() {
  /* Move the creation of all variables within the function
     in which they're being used: */
  const button = document.createElement('button'),
    ul = document.getElementById('list'),
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    item = document.getElementById('input').value;

  // here we use String.prototype.trim() to remove leading
  // and trailing whitespace from the entered value, to
  // prevent a string of white-space ('   ') being considered
  // valid:
  if (item.trim() === '') {
    alert("Input field can not be empty");
  } else {
    button.textContent = "Delete";

    // here we again use String.prototype.trim(), this time to
    // avoid the creation of a '                      task              '
    // with extraneous white-space:
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("- " + item.trim()));
    // appending the <button> to the <li> instead
    // of the <ul> (of which it would be an invalid
    // child element anyway):
    li.appendChild(button);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("input").value = ''; //clears input
}

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) //allows items to be added with enter button
{
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    handleAddNewItem();
  }
}

// the e - the EventObject - is passed automagically from
// the later use of EventTarget.addEventListener():
function clearDom(e) {

  // e.target is the element on which the event that we're
  // reacting to was originally fired (the <button>):
  const clickedButton = e.target;

  // here we use DOM traversal methods to find the closest
  // ancestor <li> element, and then use ChildNode.remove()
  // to remove it from the DOM:
  clickedButton.closest('li').remove();
}

// using event-delegation to catch the
// delete-button clicks:
// first we retrieve the element already on the page which
// will be an ancestor of the appended elements:
document.getElementById('list')
  // we then bind the clearDom() function - note the deliberate
  // lack of parentheses - as the 'click' event-handler:
  .addEventListener('click', clearDom);
```

```js
function handleAddNewItem() {
  /* Creating all variables within the function: */
  const button = document.createElement('button'),
    ul = document.getElementById('list'),
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    item = document.getElementById('input').value;

  if (item.trim() === '') {
    alert("Input field can not be empty");
  } else {
    button.textContent = "Delete";
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("- " + item));
    li.appendChild(button);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("input").value = '';
}

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    handleAddNewItem();
  }
}

function clearDom(e) {
  const clickedButton = e.target;
  clickedButton.closest('li').remove();
}

document.getElementById('list')
  .addEventListener('click', clearDom);
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
<button id="add_button" onclick="handleAddNewItem()">ADD</button>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

While this question is already, arguably, already answered, I had a few moments to spare and took advantage of this question to begin learning how to use custom elements. The code, as above, is explained so far as possible using comments in the code itself:

```js
// using an Immediately-Invoked Function
// Expression ('IIFE') to handle the creation of the
// custom element:
(function() {

  // creating an HTML <template> element, this could
  // instead be placed in, and retrieved from, the DOM:
  const template = document.createElement('template');

  // using a template literal to create, and format
  // the HTML of the created <template> (using a template
  // literal allows for new-lines and indentation):
  template.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        *, ::before, ::after {
         padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        div.layout {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content;
        }
        div.buttonWrap {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: flex-start;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="layout">
       <p></p>
        <div class="buttonWrap">
        <button>delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  `;

  // using class syntax:
  class TaskItem extends HTMLElement {
    // the constructor for the class and, by extension,
    // the element that we're defining/creating:
    constructor() {
      // it seems that super() must be placed as the
      // first thing in the constructor function:
      super();

      // we're holding the contents of the custom
      // element in the Shadow DOM, to avoid its
      // descendants being affected by CSS in the
      // parent page and to prevent JavaScript in
      // the document from interacting with the
      // contents:
      this.attachShadow({
        // we want to interact and use elements in
        // the Shadow Root, so it must be 'open'
        // (although 'closed' is the other valid
        // mode-type:
        mode: 'open'
      });

      // here we append the content - not the node
      // itself - of the created <template> element
      // using Node.cloneNode(), the Boolean true
      // means that the descendant elements are also
      // cloned and therefore appended:
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(
        template.content.cloneNode(true)
      );

      // for easier reading we cache the shadowRoot
      // here (otherwise line-lengths can be a bit
      // silly):
      const root = this.shadowRoot,

        // retrieving the <button> element, which will
        // handle the task deletion:
        del = root.querySelector('button');

      // binding the anonymous function - defined
      // using an Arrow function as we don't
      // want to change the 'this' in the function -
      // as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
      del.addEventListener('click', () =>
        // here we traverse to the parentNode of
        // the 'this', and then use
        // parentNode.removeChild() to remove the
        // 'this' node:
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this));
    }

    // this callback is executed when the element is
    // connected/attached to the DOM:
    connectedCallback() {
      // we find the Shadow Root:
      this.shadowRoot

        // find the descendent <p> element:
        .querySelector('p')

        // and set its text-content to be equal
        // to that of the data-task attribute:
        .textContent = this.dataset.task;
    }
  }

  // here we define the custom element and its
  // class:
  window.customElements.define('task-item', TaskItem);
})();

// here we cache a reference to the <button> which will
// cause the addition of new tasks:
const addTask = document.getElementById('add_button'),

  // define the function that will handle the
  // addition of new tasks:
  createTask = () => {

    // caching the <input> element:
    const taskSource = document.getElementById('input'),
      // retrieving and trimming the entered
      // <input> value:
      task = taskSource.value.trim(),

      // creating a new element (custom
      // elements are created the same way
      // as 'normal' elements):
      createdTask = document.createElement('task-item');

    // updating the data-task attribute, for
    // retrieval/use later when the element
    // is added to the DOM:
    createdTask.dataset.task = task;

    // if we have a task (a zero-length/empty
    // string is considered falsey, a string
    // with a length greater than zero is
    // considered truthy and string with negative
    // length is considered impossible (I think),
    // and therefore falsey:
    if (task) {

      // we retrieve the element holding the
      // <task-item> elements:
      document.getElementById('list')

        // and append the created element:
        .appendChild(createdTask);
    }

    // removing the <input> element's value:
    taskSource.value = '';

  };

// adding createTask() as the event-handler for
// the 'click' event on the <button>:
addTask.addEventListener('click', createTask);

// binding an anonymous function as the handler for
// keyup events on the <body> (binding to a closer
// ancestor would be more sensible in production):
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  // if the e.which is 13 we trust that to be the
  // enter key, and then we call createTask()
  if (e.which === 13) {
    createTask();
  }
})
```

```css
#list {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  background: transparent radial-gradient(at 0 0, skyblue, lime);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

#list:empty::before {
  content: 'Add a new task!';
  background: transparent linear-gradient(to right, #fffa, #fff0);
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}

task-item {
  border: 2px solid lime;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: #fff9;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" class="add_task" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
<button id="add_button" class="add_task">ADD</button>
<div id="list"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u6j25aqx/).

- [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).
- [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).
- [Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.attachShadow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow).
- [`Event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
- [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`super()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).
- [`Window.customElements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/customElements).

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The code very well explained. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not very nice but a solution :)

```
else {
   button.innerText = 'Delete';
   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('- ' + item));
   ul.appendChild(li);
   let but = button.cloneNode(true); // <-- solution
   li.appendChild(but);

   // clearDom function
   clearDom();
}
```

And also a function that erases a single entry

```
function clearDom() {
   let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button:not(#add_button)');
   for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
       buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          e.target.parentNode.remove();
       }, false);
   }
}
```

```js
let button = document.createElement('button');
let ul = document.getElementById('list');
let li = document.createElement('li');

function handleAddNewItem() {
  let item = document.getElementById('input').value;
  let ul = document.getElementById('list');
  let li = document.createElement('li');

  if (item === '') {
    alert('Input field can not be empty');
  }
  else {
    button.innerText = 'Delete';
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('- ' + item));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    let but = button.cloneNode(true);
    li.appendChild(but);

    clearDom();
  }
  document.getElementById('input').value = ''; // clears input
}

function clearDom() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button:not(#add_button)');
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.target.parentNode.remove();
    }, false);
  }
}

document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    handleAddNewItem();
  }
};
```

```html
  <input id="input" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
  <button id="add_button" onclick="handleAddNewItem()">ADD</button>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: i am new to javascript. Can you clarify 3 things for me? 'button:not(#add_button)' i understand it is excluding add_button. Can you tell me what other variations or how this code came about or any reference so that i can have a deeper understanding of this code and other similar codes(for learning purpose). No 2, is why do we have to loop upto and excluding button.length and what is button.length? No 3 can you explain e and e.target.parentNode. I dont think i understand it properly like i should. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: By the way this worked for me. Had been working on this for some time. i am glad i posted it up here, learning a lot about javascript. Please do answer my questions. Specially no1 and 2.

Comment: @Brian 1. This is css, and what `document.querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` is doing is fetching elements with this kind of css "tag" (e.g. "p", "p.cssClass", or "p.cssID". What I mean by "tag" is that in your css stylesheets, you can use these "tags" to select and style certain elements). So, this specific example is using the :not pseudo-class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

Comment: @Brian  2.  Part 1: `buttons.length` is getting the length of the html collection (basically an array with html elements) given to you by `document.querySelectorAll` or other variants (like `document.getElementById`, etc.) of that. Basically, we are getting the amount of buttons that is not the add button. This amount just gives us the number of remove buttons. Then, the loop is a classic example of a for loop, getting the indices of each element in the HTML collection. We then access each item in the HTML collection by using `buttons[i]`. You could just use a for loop using of, but whatever.

Comment: @Brian 2. Part 2: Now, for every remove button, we add an event listener. and what our event listener here is that it is getting the `click` event, or when you click the remove button. And once the click event happens, the function (the second argument) is called with an event as the first parameter.We then look at the todo element itself, using `e.target.parentNode`, and remove it. This is why the remove button works. For more details about events and event listeners, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events.